# State Transition Diagrams with R

Tags: r

Does anybody know how to creat such a graph?

[image]

Comment: Show some code you tried...

Answer (score 4):

You can get a pretty good approximation to your graph using the `igraph` package. 
The code below sets up the edges as a data.frame, then turns it into a graph using `graph_from_data_frame`.  You could just plot at that point, but while it would have the same content as your graph, it would not look like your graph. So there are several steps to make it look the way that you asked.

`C` is the curvature of the edges. I made them all be straight (curvature = 0) except the two between nodes 0 and 3. I did not want these to be on top of each other so I gave them a small curvature.

`LO` is a layout to arrange the nodes in the same pattern at you did.

The `edge.loop.angle` parameter is so that the loop from 0 to itself would lay out nicely.

Finally, default color for the nodes is an orange-yellow, so I changed it to white like in your picture.

```
library(igraph)

from = c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3)
to   = c(0,1,2,3,2,3,0)
weight = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4, 1,1,1)

Edges = data.frame(from,to,weight)
g = graph_from_data_frame(Edges)

C = rep(0,7)
C[c(4,7)] = 0.15

LO = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0), ncol=2)

plot(g, edge.label=E(g)$weight, layout=LO, edge.loop.angle=-pi/2,
    vertex.color="white", edge.curved=C)
```

[image: Network plot]